# Static url goes after the regular page url

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

My static files only load on index page, but when navigating to another page like: examle_url/page, it returns a 404 error since it loads it like that: http://127.0.0.1:8000/categories/default/static/js/main.js, see the static loads after page

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root/')


STATICFILES_DIRS = (
  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static/base'),
)
```

urls.py "all my urls are in main directory and then i import views from apps"

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('profile/', profile, name="profile"),
    path('', index, name="index"),
    path('category/', category, name="category"),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

If it matters my load static files are all in theme.html file and is then extended in all other html files.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: You should mention ```{% load static %}``` on top of every template (or the base template) to load the static files...

Comment: @SwetankPoddar: I'm not convinced that is the issue, how would this otherwise have generated the href in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should prepend the [**`STATIC_URL`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#static-url) with a *slash*:

```
# settings.py

# …
# with a leading slash
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
# …
```

If you do not do that, then the url will look like `static/js/main.js`. If the path does not start with a slash, then that is *relative* to path the *current* URL, and thus if the page is `/categories/default`, it will look at `/categories/default/static/js/main.js`.

Comment: Thanks you right. the url problem does get fixed but the static file then gets a 404, even on the home page. any idea what might cause it?

Comment: @YankiSegal: your file is stored at `static_root/js/main.js`? Where exactly is the file itself stored (relative to the base of your project)?

Comment: Nevermind the problem was that i changed the static dir to '/static/base' end forget to move the files my bad sorry thanks